# Merge lines of text in ONE big column using BATCH

Tags: batch-file

I have several hundreds of different txt files (ranging from TXT1 to TXT 2000), located in a single folder and I would like to merge all TXTs as follows using batch:

```
TXT1             TXT2           TXT2       etc      TXT2000    
line 001       line 101       line 501              line 90000
(...)           (...)          (...)                   (...)
line 100       line 500       line 550              line 100000
```

Before merging, the first two lines of each TXT file should be deleted. After merging I would have a single file TXTall.txt as:

```
TXTall
line 003
line 004
(...)
line 100000
```

Any help?

Comment: Have you written any code yourself yet? Also, do you really need to use batch files for this? It would be much simpler in, say, python.

Comment: Oh wait, I misunderstood the question. It's actually easy :)

Comment: So what's the deal about the lines being in different columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the copy command:

```
copy TXT*.txt TXTall.txt
```

This will append all files with names matching `TXT*.txt` together and save the whole thing into a file called `TXTall.txt`.

I'm not sure whether you can rely on the ordering being sensible. I suggest you test it and see if works for you.

**Update:** To skip the first two lines of each file, try this:

```
@echo off
for %%f in (txt*.txt) do (
    for /F "delims= skip=2" %%t in (%%f) do (
        echo %%t >> AllTxt.txt
    )
)
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and clarify what you want then? Are they not already in a single column? Are there any other rules you didn't mention (like ignore the first two lines)?

Comment: Question edited. Each information inside the TXT files are in single columns. However If I use the code as suggested above, the appended TXTall will be a single mass of line

Comment: The single line thing is weird, it doesn't do that for me. Do these files have `\r\n` or `\n` line endings?

Comment: I can't really understand that without formatting, can you edit it into your question?

Comment: As for short testing, since I manipulate 1000 files, the names of my 5 TXT files have only 8 chr in length and the text they contain have no \r\n or \n line endings. Each TXT begins with the text "Line". I get a single big line in return if I use your first suggestion. Ex: Line01-111Line02-222Line03-333Line04-444Line05-555. If I use your second suggestion, it yields an empty file. If I use your second suggestion, but erase the line for %%f "delims etc, I obtain a sequence of 5 values (%t %t %t %t %t) pilled up in one single column. At least, now, this "one single column thing" worked :)

Comment: the text files have *no* line endings? So they are all one line each? Again, please edit your question, I can't understand what you're saying without formatting.

Comment: Hi Blorgbeard. Your script in the "second suggestion" should have the "setlocal enabledelayedexpansion" command after @echo off. Now it works flawlessly! Thanks a lot for your time. Problem solved

Comment: Ahaha, I forget I have that turned on by default - sorry for the confusion :)

Comment: Thank you for your time. I am using this script and everything is fine!